# How to combine two lists of lists element-wise?

Tags: python, list, time-series, reorderlist

In Python, I would like to combine lists of lists in a very specific way, but I could not find it yet. Any ideas are welcome!

With the following input:

```
firstList = [[[1], [2], [3]], [[4], [5], [6]]]
secondList = [[[11], [12], [13]], [[14], [15], [16]]]
```

I would like to get the following output:

```
[[[1, 11], [2, 12], [3, 13]], [[4, 14], [5, 15], [6, 16]]]
```

I tried:

```
[list(a) for a in zip(firstList, secondList)]
```

but this returns:

```
[[[[1], [2], [3]], [[11], [12], [13]]], [[[4], [5], [6]], [[14], [15], [16]]]]
```

I need the desired output to get the correct format to be able to use the function `TimeSeriesKMeans()` from the module `tslearn` with time series in 2 dimensions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are having nested lists, you need to double `zip` through your list. You can do:

```
[[a + b for a, b in zip(x, y)] for x, y in zip(firstList, secondList)]
```

**Code**:

```
firstList = [[[1], [2], [3]], [[4], [5], [6]]]
secondList = [[[11], [12], [13]], [[14], [15], [16]]]

result = [[a + b for a, b in zip(x, y)] for x, y in zip(firstList, secondList)]
# [[[1, 11], [2, 12], [3, 13]], [[4, 14], [5, 15], [6, 16]]]
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Really great answer, very elegantly coded!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain

result = [list(zip(chain(*l1), chain(*l2)))
          for l1, l2 in zip(firstList, secondList)]
```